# $pylab inline invalid syntax

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to follow [this PCA tutorial](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_pca_step_by_step.html#drop_labels) and have hit a roadblock when trying to start pylab with

```
$pylab inline
```

Where I get a Syntax error. I am using Anaconda/Spyder with Python 3.4, and I do have Pylab installed. I apologize if this a silly question, I have not used python in quite a while.

Comment: It's `%pylab inline`, just like it says in your link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Same error.

Comment: Are you running the code in IPython/Jupyter?

Comment: No. IPython is buggy for me and I am currently installing Jupyter (are they the same thing? Used command "conda install jupyter") to see if that works. I'm running it from the Spyder IDE

Comment: The `%` commands are IPython [magic commands](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html), and don't work if you're just running a program without it.

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot. Now let's see if I can get IPython to work...

Comment: No problem. Getting IPython to work shouldn't be too hard. `pip install -U ipython jupyter` will install everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

Providing the specific syntax error makes it easier to understand the problem.  In my case (IPython 4.0.0, python 2.7, anaconda), I get:

```
In [1]: %pylab inline
UsageError: Invalid GUI request u'inline', valid ones are: pyglet, osx, qt5, qt, glut, gtk, gtk3, tk, wx
```

I don't know if the "%pylab inline" syntax is from an older or a newer version than I have.

Regardless, without a working IPython package, you can still get interactive plot behaviour from matplotlib by doing the following:

```
>>> import pylab
>>> pylab.interactive(True)
>>> pylab.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,1])
```

This should show the plot, allowing you to interact with it, while still returning you to the console for the next command.